# In what issue did Genis-Vell ressurrect Elysius?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, episode-identification

Does anyone know of an issue where Genis-Vell resurrects of his mother? I think Dr Strange was involved and it happened after her death in Warlock (published 1998) and before her appearance in Captain Marvel 14 (2published 2003). But I can't find the issue. Captain Marvel 18 (published 2004) mentions that in another reality Genis brought Elysius back to life using a combination of magic and technology which I think is a reference to comic that actually was published.

Comment: "*She was killed by the resurrected body of Mar-Vell, but was later resurrected due to alterations in the timeline made by Genis. -Captain Marvel#59-62, Marvel Spotlight (v.2)#1-3, Incredible Hulk#245, 247-248, Death of Captain Marvel graphic novel, Avengers#230, Silver Surfer Annual#6, Cosmic Powers#4, Captain Marvel (v.2)#2, 5-6, Warlock (v.4)#1, Captain Marvel (v.3)#32, Captain Marvel (v.4)#15-1*" - Is this what you're referring to? - http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Elysius_(Earth-616)

Comment: @Valorum Yes, the explanation for her resurrection is that Genis altered the timeline to one in which an alternate version of himself was able to resurrect her. I think the actual resurrection itself which took place in that timeline was portrayed in a comic, but I can't remember which one it was. I might be confused though and it just was never shown.

Comment: ? http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/File:Captain_Marvel_Vol_3_6.jpg ?

Comment: http://marvelite.prohosting.com/surfer/cmarvel/guide2.html

Answer (score 0):

From Valorum's comments:

> "She was killed by the resurrected body of Mar-Vell, but was later resurrected due to alterations in the timeline made by Genis. -Captain Marvel#59-62, Marvel Spotlight (v.2)#1-3, Incredible Hulk#245, 247-248, Death of Captain Marvel graphic novel, Avengers#230, Silver Surfer Annual#6, Cosmic Powers#4, Captain Marvel (v.2)#2, 5-6, Warlock (v.4)#1, Captain Marvel (v.3)#32, Captain Marvel (v.4)#15-1" - Is this what you're referring to? - marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Elysius_(Earth-616) –
> Valorum
> May 19, 2016 at 20:23

> @Valorum Yes, the explanation for her resurrection is that Genis altered the timeline to one in which an alternate version of himself was able to resurrect her. I think the actual resurrection itself which took place in that timeline was portrayed in a comic, but I can't remember which one it was. I might be confused though and it just was never shown. –
> MEGR
> May 19, 2016 at 23:57

> ? marvel.wikia.com/wiki/File:Captain_Marvel_Vol_3_6.jpg ? –
> Valorum
> May 20, 2016 at 0:14

> marvelite.prohosting.com/surfer/cmarvel/guide2.html
> Valorum
> May 20, 2016 at 0:17

The last link explaining that [Veeda Leebre](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Veeda_Leebre_(Earth-616)#The_Restoration) restored the people of Carmondy IV in Captain Marvel Vol. 2 #6 (May 1996), and that Elysius appeared in the issue, but had no connection to anything else?

> Meanwhile, Elysius appears to be harmed by some unknown force on Titan, while, on Calculex, the Grand Master recruits one of Genis's friends, Zoog, to participate in the Dead Man's Hand.  [...]
> This issue marked the end of the Genis's first Captain Marvel series.  The stories concerning the Grand Master and the Dead Man's Hand were never revisited, as well as what happened to Elysius.